# android custom bitmap overlay with mapsforge

Tags: android, bitmap, maps

I'm trying to overlay a bitmap over a map on android using the mapsforge mapping library. I'm extending the Overlay class, and I need to implement the drawOverlayBitmap. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? I've googled, but all the results come back using google's apis, and when you override the method there, you have the mapView so that makes more sense... not sure how to do it here

```
public abstract class Overlay extends java.lang.Thread {
private static final java.lang.String THREAD_NAME = "Overlay";
private boolean changedSize;
private boolean hasValidDimensions;
private final android.graphics.Matrix matrix;
private float matrixScaleFactor;
private android.graphics.Bitmap overlayBitmap1;
private android.graphics.Bitmap overlayBitmap2;
private final android.graphics.Canvas overlayCanvas;
private final android.graphics.Point point;
private android.graphics.Point positionAfterDraw;
private android.graphics.Point positionBeforeDraw;
private boolean redraw;
protected org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView internalMapView;

protected Overlay() { /* compiled code */ }

public final void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) { /* compiled code */ }

public final void matrixPostScale(float scaleX, float scaleY, float pivotX, float pivotY) { /* compiled code */ }

public final void matrixPostTranslate(float translateX, float translateY) { /* compiled code */ }

public boolean onLongPress(org.mapsforge.core.GeoPoint geoPoint, org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView mapView) { /* compiled code */ }

public final void onSizeChanged() { /* compiled code */ }

public boolean onTap(org.mapsforge.core.GeoPoint geoPoint, org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView mapView) { /* compiled code */ }

public final void requestRedraw() { /* compiled code */ }

public final void run() { /* compiled code */ }

public final void setupOverlay(org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView mapView) { /* compiled code */ }

private void redrawOverlay() { /* compiled code */ }

protected abstract void drawOverlayBitmap(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, android.graphics.Point point, org.mapsforge.android.maps.Projection projection, byte b);

protected java.lang.String getThreadName() { /* compiled code */ }

final void changeSize() { /* compiled code */ }

boolean sizeHasChanged() { /* compiled code */ }

protected static final enum EventType {
    public static final  LONG_PRESS, public static final  TAP;

    public static org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.Overlay.EventType[] values() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay.Overlay.EventType valueOf(java.lang.String name) { /* compiled code */ }

    private EventType() { /* compiled code */ }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code as example:

```
Point screenPts = new Point();

@Override
protected void drawOverlayBitmap(Canvas canvas, Point point, 
                  Projection projection, byte zoom){

        projection.toPixels(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),
                  (int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6)) , screenPts);
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, screenPts.x, screenPts.y, new Paint());
}
```

Regards.

Comment: sweet! good call. i tried something like this, but didnt get it right. thanks!

Comment: I extended ArrayWayOverlay but couldnt get it to work, I am trying to add a text to my image...So I called super on drawOverlayBitmap and after this I tryed canvas.drawText....I am doing it wrong?

Comment: I am trying to do something extrememly similar in adding text to each of my items in my ArrayItemizedOverlay - I have overloaded the drawoverlaybitmap function, but i do not have a location (where did this come from in your example?) - the itemPosition is private and cannot be exposed, so how am I suppose to display text for each item ?